# Laravel: I get wrong database

Tags: php, laravel

I am not new to Laravel but I encounter a weird problem that never seen before. There are two projects on localhost named `core` implemented by Laravel and `log` implemented by Lumen. The `core` posts some data to `log` and `log` is responsible to store those data in its own database.

The is the `core` .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:rAfY+jMXkAsPz+wBrDksLNsPCLYzfNLI+FISLfqZ/1s=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/core

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=core
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_EXPIRE=14400

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and this is the .env file of `log` project

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/log
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=log
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

Inside the `log` project there is a model Log

```
class Log extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['entity_type', 'entity_id', 'user_id', 'metadata', 'action'];
    protected $table = 'logs';
}
```

with this migration

```
class CreateLogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('entity_type')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('entity_id')->nullable();
            $table->index(['entity_type', 'entity_id']);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->index('user_id');
            $table->text('metadata')->nullable();
            $table->enum('action', ['create', 'edit', 'delete', 'report']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('logs');
    }
}
```

when I run the migration it creates the table in the log database. The `log` contains only one function in a controller as follow

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'metadata' => 'sometimes|json',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'action' => 'required|in:create,edit,delete,report',
        'entity_id' => 'required',
        'entity_type' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json(['error' => true]);

    try {
        Log::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(['error' => false]);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

and finally this is the code which posts data from `core` to `log` via Guzzle inside a trait (I should mention that I also ran this code in controller too):

```
    static::updated(function (Model $model) {
        $data = [
            'entity_type' => self::$tableModelMapper[$model->getTable()],
            'entity_id' => $model->getAttribute('id'),
            'user_id' => optional(auth()->user())->id,
            'metadata' => json_encode($model->getDirty()),
            'action' => 'edit'
        ];

        $client = new Client();
        $client->post('http://localhost/log/public/store',
            [
                'json' => $data
            ]);
    });
```

The problem is:

When I post data from postman to `log` like this

```
{
    "metadata":"{\"name\": \"Alex\",\"family\": \"Nicole\"}",
    "user_id": 1,
    "action": "create",
    "entity_id": 12,
    "entity_type":"Order"
}
```

it successfully creates the data in `log` database and logs table. But when I post from `core` to `log` by the code given above, it reports error

> Server error: `POST http://localhost/log/public/store` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!-- SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'core.logs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `logs` (`en (truncated...)

As you see, it says `Table 'core.logs' doesn't exist` while the logs table is in `log` database and the data insert to logs table is inside `log` project, then why `core` expects to have logs table?!!!

## test

To find out why it happens I added the following codes `store` function of `log` project

```
    $result = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($result);
```

when I post via postman it prints `log` in log file but when I post via `core` it prints `core` in log file. Thus when I post via `core` it tried to access the core database inside the log project!!

What is wrong here?

Comment: Probably incorrect URLs are being used somewhere, so your web server is directing the request to the other project. Check your server access logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe its because the nameserver is similar `http://localhost/core` and `http://localhost/log` the system will confuse are they different service or not.

i suggest you, to change the port number one of your service, example:

your logs to `http://localhost:8080/log`

Comment: Yes it was because of that. Thanks